# Unlist multiple lists in R

Tags: r, list, loops, foreach

how to unlist multiple lists at once?

Given I a range of list (usually more than 10) like these that I want to unlist:

```
ice_2000 = list(seq(1,5,1),seq(6,10,1),seq(11,15,1))
ice_1990 = list(seq(1,5,1),seq(6,10,1),seq(11,15,1))
ice_1980 = list(seq(1,5,1),seq(6,10,1),seq(11,15,1))
```

I have tried something like:

```
sample.yrs = c(2000,2005,2010)

nam <- paste("ice",sample.yrs, sep = "_") 

library(foreach) 


foreach(x = nam) %do% { 

temp.df <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind",x))
assign(paste("df",x, sep="_"), temp.df )}
```

How do I get to call the individual list by their names from a vector in such a way that they are recognized as list objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `get`:

```
get("ice_2000")
```

But why not simply:

```
lapply(list(ice_2000, ice_1990, ice_1980) , unlist)
```

It's far better practice to store your structures in a list rather than randomly in memory and then trying to grab them with ugly paste/string operations plus get ...

And if you need to correct this structural default, you can do:

```
library(magrittr)

good = ls(pattern="ice_*") %>% lapply(get) %>% lapply(function(u) do.call(rbind, u))
```

Comment: I think because OP doesn't feel like typing out all `ice_*`.

Comment: yes but the last line of code deals with this issue.

Comment: It's far better to put these objects in a list when they are created. If that is not possible (can't imagine why not) you should use `mget` instead of `lapply` with `get`.

Comment: And OP doesn't seem to want `unlist` but `do.call(rbind, ...)`.

Comment: I am dealing with sea ice data that comes in annual files .bin which I read into R. Each year is a list of `[[365]]` list objects with `[1]...[108]` values. Would you recommend storing them as a list of list? @ColonelBeauvel also how could I use your statement `good = ls(pattern="ice_*") %>% lapply(get) %>% lapply(unlist)` with `do.call(rbind, ...)` ?

Comment: yes it's far better to store these in a list. I updated the code so that you can manage your do.call code.